# Get XML data from PHP file url

Tags: php, xml

i would lik get data from my xml file with php

my xml file is :

```
<cws-status-resp ver="1.0">

  <proxy-users count="1" login-failures="1">

    <user name="0d03b2451232c" display-name="0d03b2451232c" sessions="1">

      <session host="197.200.9.251" id="2028566" count="1/1" active="true" profile="*" client-id="Mgcamd" protocol="ExtNewcamd" context="UserID [2] CaID [0000] Providers [1] [00 00 00] Anonymous [Yes]" connected="Wed, 27 Aug 2014 11:59:35 +0100" duration="43m 51s" ecm-count="331" emm-count="0" pending-count="0" keepalive-count="3" last-transaction="619" last-zap="36m 32s" idle-time="1s" flags="C" avg-ecm-interval="9">
        <service id="6515" cdata="1973:003311" name="NatGeo Wild HD France" profile="secahd" />
      </session>

    </user>

  </proxy-users>

</cws-status-resp>
```

i need to echo only this name="NatGeo Wild HD France" from my xml

thanks for answers

Comment: We need to see the code you've tried.

Comment: Use [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) then loop on the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem only to have one `<service>` per XML item, simply

```
//$xml contains the XML mentioned in OP
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('service')->item(0)->getAttribute('name');
```

outputs

> NatGeo Wild HD France

Answer (score 0):

since you have only one service node you can do this :

```
$XmlFile=simplexml_load_file("RightYourPathHere");

echo $XmlFile->csw-status-resp->proxy-users->session->service['name'];

?>
```

if you have serveral service nodes you can do this :

```
foreach($XmlFile->csw-status-resp->proxy-users->session->service as $Service){

echo $Service['name'];

}
```